# How can I have MySQL Workbench autocomplete with uppercase?

Tags: mysql-workbench

By default, autocompletion is lowercase. Is there any way to have it uppercase?

[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I submitted [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69621):

> Description: The autocompletion uses lowercase instead of uppercase,
>   which is inconsistent with the SQL generated e.g. when altering a
>   table, as well as with the ANSI standard
>   http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt Demo:
>   http://youtu.be/oRcjJcaej-M
>
> How to repeat: In the SQL Editor, type "AL" then hit Ctrl+Space to
>   trigger the auto completion. Demo: http://youtu.be/oRcjJcaej-M
>
> Suggested fix: Use uppercase.

The issue is now solved:

> Fixed as of the upcoming MySQL Workbench 6.0.4 release, and here's the
>   changelog entry:
>
> A new preference was added to toggle casing for the generated keywords
>   in the auto completion list. "Edit", "Preferences", "SQL Editor TAB",
>   "Use uppercase keyboards on completion".

[image]

Comment: restart MySQL Workbench after.

Comment: Shouldn't MySQL functions be upper case too? (they are still lower case with this option)

Comment: MySQL Workbench 8.0.29 and functions still lowercase when completion set to UPPERCASE.

Answer (score 9):

In MySQL WOrkbench, go to EDIT > PREFERENCES > SQL EDITOR > QUERY EDITOR and in productivity section click on the checkbox with "Use UPPERCASE keywords on completion".

Comment: Hi Urwa, welcome! This answer seems to say the same thing as the currently accepted answer from 2013, but without the pretty illustration. You might get down-voted. The menu path you show _is_ slightly different though ("QUERY EDITOR"?) - does that mean the accepted answer is wrong? If so, better to delete this and correct the other answer, especially if this is changed since v6.0.4.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the contents of your `%PROGRAM_FILES%\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\data\code_editor.xml` with the contents from http://pastebin.com/FHVPLAP4